# Hook up MU site creation

Tags: multisite, hooks

I want to write a plugin so I can hook up the `wp_install_defaults` function.

I actually need to do the following: when a new site is created, I want to import a default XML file with some categories and default posts. `wp_install_defaults` is the function that does that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Isn't `wp_install_defaults` hook-able?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wpmu_new_blog` action hook which accepts 6 arguments:

- $blog_id
- $user_id
- $domain
- $path
- $site_id
- $meta